# How to debug AURemoteIO::IOThread exception?

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit

I'm working with audio units and at some point in my program, if I add an exception breakpoint, I can catch a CoreAudio exception from the `IOThread`. This is what I see:

[image]

[image]

Now, there is really not enough information in that for me to be able to debug it(or maybe there is, but I don't know how to use it). So, how can I debug it? Most intriguing is that, for some reason, if I remove the exception breakpoint, the sound *seems* to be all right, and the program works as expected. Still, I bet the exception has a reason and it's healthy to find and fix it.

Comment: Is there a call stack available when you're at that breakpoint?

Comment: There is, forgot to put it up. Will update question.

Comment: Throwing in operator new[] might indicate an out-of-memory condition, or maybe an exception in your VoiceZone constructor.  Take a look at how much memory your app is consuming, and maybe review the VoiceZone constructor for something that might itself throw an exception; or maybe a VoiceZone instance is simply extremely large for some reason you don't expect.

Comment: out-of-memory seems likely since if I make the number of tracks smaller (I use this with the ios midi player) I don't get the exception anymore. But is ridiculous small (3 tracks). I will check it with instruments and see if the memory is the problem.

Comment: nope, it's not a memory problem, although my program has a much bigger memory footprint than it should (around 25MB).